# Need some basic info to develop mobile website in Android

Tags: android, web-applications

I would like to develop an Android app to access our web site. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WebView in your application to show your website. WebView it is a widget built into android using it to display html content. Enable the internet access through the Manifest file.

**Adding a WebView to Your Application**

To add a WebView to your Application, simply include the  element in your activity layout. For example, here's a layout file in which the WebView fills the screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

To load a web page in the WebView, use loadUrl(). For example:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

Answer (score 3):

see here: [Web Applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

This is a very broad question.  However, at the highest level, you're most likely going to want to add an interface to your website that supports either JSON or XML as a means to request information.  You would then configure your application to request the JSON or XML, parse it, and display it, rather than the user viewing the HTML that is currently served.  Alternatively, you could develop a version of your site that is designed to be viewed on the device.